# Using argv in C?

Tags: c, argv

For an assignment, I am required to have command line arguments for my C program. I've used argc/argv before (in C++) without trouble, but I'm unsure if C style strings are affecting how this works. Here is the start of my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  if(argc>1){
    printf("0 is %s, 1 is %s\n",argv[0],argv[1]);
    if(argv[1]=="-e"){
        // Do some stuff with argv[2]
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else{
        printf("Error: Incorrect usage - first argument must be -e");
        return 0;
    }
  }
```

So I am calling my program as "program.exe -e myargstuff" but I am getting the "Error: Incorrect Usage..." output, even though my printf() tells me that argv[1] is "-e". Some help, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The line

```
if(argv[1]=="-e"){
```

compares pointers, not strings. Use the [strcmp](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strcmp.html) function instead:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1],"-e")==0){
```

Comment: Haha. 6 answers just like mine in the time it took me to write the answer.

Comment: Well, that absolutely did it. Thank you for correcting this, I'm very new to C!

Answer (score 7):

Change:

```
if(argv[1]=="-e"){
```

to

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0){
```

and include `string.h`.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [`getopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) and related functions; it'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare c-strings like that. Use strcmp (reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/)).

Because c-strings are actually pointers, the == operator compares the address of the first character which will never be equal in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `==` to compare strings like that in C. That's just comparing the addresses of argv[1] and your literal, which are pretty much guaranteed to be different.

Use `strcmp` instead. eg:

```
if (!strcmp("-e", argv[1])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of the main function says you're dealing with `char*` pointers. In C, there is no operator overloading; therefore, `==` between two `char*` will test if they **point to the same place**. This is not the case, and is rarely the case at all. Use the [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) (the reference for the function is valid even though it points to a C++ site) function from `<string.h>`:

```
strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0
```